# Need to toggle selected divs, and a increment a counter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to allow users to click on a series of divs.  They're basically selecting x number of items (each item is in a div) to add to a group.  Each item can only be added once.  But they should also be able to unselect items as well.

Each time an item is selected, it's id is added to a form field, so I can capture a comma delimited list of all the selected item IDs.

Only x number of items can be selected.  So I need to keep a running count of items selected and both stop the ability to select additional items.  Of course if a selected item is unselected, the count would increment down.

What I have now, adds the correct item ID to the form field, and correctly toggles the div style on and off each time it's clicked.  However, it just keeps adding ID's to the form field.  No limit for 'x' number, and no removal of IDs when an item is unselected.

Any help would be awesome sauce.

Here's the html:

```
    <h3 style="border-top:none;padding-top:0;">Choose <div id="boxQ">3</div> Items for Your Box</h3>
{% set featuredCollection = 'clctn-box-items'|collection %}
{% for product in featuredCollection.products %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="twelve columns">
            <div class="box-items" id="tag{{ product.id }}" value="{{ product.id }}">
               {{ product.name }} <img class="box-item-thumb" align="right" src="{{ product.images.first.thumbnail('auto', 65)|default('http://placehold.it/100x65') }}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
<input type="text" id="boxItemIDs" name="box_item_ids" value="">
```

Here's the css:

```
.box-items {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-left: 4px solid #ff7b01;
    min-height:75px;
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#efefef;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.itemClicked {background-color:grey;}
```

Here's the jquery:

```
//
// Set Selected Item Count - numer of items allowed for this box 
//
var itemCount;
$( function() {
    var urlString = window.location.href;
    var thesplit = urlString.substring(urlString.lastIndexOf("/")+1).split('-');
    itemCount = thesplit[0];

});
//
// Handle Box Item Clicks
//
var count = 0;
$( document ).ready(function() {

    document.getElementById("boxQ").innerHTML = itemCount;

    $('div[id^="tag"]').on('click', function() {  
        var $thisDiv = $( this );
        count++;
        $thisDiv.toggleClass( "itemClicked");
        var ids = $(this).attr('value');
        var resultObj = $("#boxItemIDs");
        var stringToAppend = resultObj.val().length > 0 ? resultObj.val() + "," : "";
        resultObj .val( stringToAppend + ids );


    });


});
```

Here's a fiddle I created for it: https://jsfiddle.net/3z1uoL8f/  It's not working though.

Comment: could you create a fiddle?  And please, give us the final client-side HTML.

Comment: I have not seen any condition defined in your code that uses `count` ?

Comment: I'll work on a fiddle for this.  I couldn't get it to run last time I tried.  I'll try again.  And the count hasn't been integrated yet...rather, I previously removed what I had tried b/c it wasn't working.

Comment: Just created a fiddle for this and added the link at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Wow, thanks all.  Ziv and Lance's solutions both work.  I'm going to go with Ziv's b/c the code's a bit cleaner.  Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the easiest way of achieving what you want:

JS:

```
var maxItems = 3;
$(function () {
    $(".box-items").click(function () {
        if ($(".itemSelected").length >= maxItems) {
            if ($(this).hasClass("itemSelected")) {
                $(this).removeClass("itemSelected");
            }
        } else {
            $(this).toggleClass("itemSelected");
        }
        var ids = "";    
        $(".itemSelected").each(function (index, item) {
          ids += $(item).attr("id")+",";
        });
        //i use slice to remove last comma
        $("#submitMe").val(ids.slice(0,-1));       
    });
});
```

Html:

```
<div class="box-items" id="1">click me</div>
<div class="box-items" id="2">click me</div>
<div class="box-items" id="3">click me</div>
<div class="box-items" id="4">click me</div>
<input id="submitMe" type="text" />
```

Fiddle: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zwuuubeq/)

Comment: Nice, clean approach. Thanks Ziv!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take on the problem. My first instinct feels that this is a bit bloated and could be slimmed down if I had more time, but hopefully this will put you in the right direction. I put up a fiddle as well so you can play with it and see how everything works together. I hope this helps!

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7pw9uz3o/1/

```
// Set Selected Item Count - arbitrary number for DEMO purposes
var itemCount = 3;
var count = 0;
var items= [];

document.getElementById("boxQ").innerHTML = itemCount;

$('div[id^="tag"]').on('click', function() {

    var $thisDiv = $( this );
    var ids = $(this).attr('value');
    var resultObj = $("#boxItemIDs");

    // If the row has been clicked already we need to remove it
    if ($thisDiv.hasClass("itemClicked")) 
    {
        $thisDiv.removeClass("itemClicked");

        var index = items.indexOf(ids);
        if (index > -1) {
            items.splice(index, 1);
        }
        resultObj.val(items.join(','));
        count--;  
    }
    else
    {
        // If count equals itemCount throw an error
        if (count === itemCount) 
        {
            console.log("Too many items in the box yo!");
            // This would be a great place to put an error message...
        }

        // Otherwise we need to continue and add it.
        else 
        {
            $thisDiv.addClass("itemClicked");
            items.push(ids);
            resultObj.val(items.join(','));
            count++;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to test it with your fiddle page (due to the handlebars(?) template not rendering properly) but, with a little rearrangement, renaming variables and a few extra operations, here's my attempt to steer you on the right path:

```
$('div[id^="tag"]').on('click', function() {  
    var $thisDiv = $( this );
    var resultObj = $("#boxItemIDs");
    var id = $thisDiv.attr('value'); 
    var selectedIds = resultObj.val().split(',');
    var idIndex = selectedIds.indexOf(id);

    // item is currently selected
    if (idIndex >= 0) {
        selectedIds.splice(idIndex, 1);
    }
    else {
        selectedIds.push(id);
    }
    count = selectedIds.length;

    $thisDiv.toggleClass( "itemClicked");
    resultObj.val( selectedIds.join(",") );
});
```